# Connection failed error when building docker image from ubuntu base image using Docker CE on macOS 10.13

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Im using Docker Community Edition v18.03 on my macOS 10.13 machine and have the following Dockerfile in my application.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN bin/setup
```

I build the image with

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

Now in the build process i see the following

[image]

The file `bin/setup` installs the ruby package on ubuntu and is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! which ruby > /dev/null; then
  echo "Installing Ruby"
  apt-get -y update
  apt-get -y install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
  apt-get -y install zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline-gplv2-dev libyaml-dev
  apt-get clean
  apt-get -y install ruby-full
fi
```

I tried adding dns settings as follows in Docker preferences but that didnt help

[image]

Why am i getting this error and how can it be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

This could potentially because you are behind a proxy, and proxy env is not set in your docker box.
You can set proxy while running `docker build` command,
(replace proxy url with your own proxy server)

```
docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://10.20.30.2:1234 --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.20.30.2:1234
```

If you are using a `Dockerfile`,

Add the following (replace proxy url with your own proxy server) after `FROM` line,

```
ENV HTTP_PROXY=http://10.20.30.2:1234
ENV HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.20.30.2:1234
```